# Admin resources are accessible without being logged in

Tags: admin

Should the `/admin/resources/assetthumbs/{assetid}/200` be accessible without being logged in?

I’ve just noticed I can access thumbnails that way, and with some fiddling even let it generate huge images for me

This is on v2.6.3002.

Comment: Is this on a local setup or live site? Any other details you could give us? What do your permissions look like?

Comment: Local and live. This isn't permission related and affects all Craft 2 sites see answer below from Brad Bell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Craft 2, this is expected behavior.

In Craft 3, we "fixed" it by using an Asset's UID instead of its ID, which makes it harder to guess.

Comment: So in Craft 2 it is possible to see al the uploaded images without logging in and scale them to any size even so big PHP runs out of memory. This seems like a serious issue to me. 


Why doesn't Craft check if the user is logged in to the admin?

Comment: For the next release asset thumbnails will only be generated on Control Panel requests by logged in users.  Going to go ahead and vote to close this as a bug.